# Resize Graph to Page

Tags: vba, charts

Currently, I have a macro that copies graphs for one workbook, copies it to a worksheet in another workbook every 35 rows apart so that they are all on a new page. With the pasted chart, how do I resize it so that it fits to the page? Right now, there is a bunch of white space around each chart on the page.This is what I have so far.

```
source.ChartObjects(i).Activate
                ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
                wsTemp.Cells(x, 1).PasteSpecial
                x = x + 35
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the chart to a *chart sheet* instead:

```
source.ChartObjects(i).Activate
ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet
```

Pasting charts 35 rows apart **does not** ensure each chart gets printed on a new page; you're at the mercy of whoever plays with the page breaks and print settings. By having each chart on its own *chart sheet*, there's no way [AFAIK] they can ever be printed on the same page. It also ensures each chart fills the entire page.

Comment: If I place everything on a new sheet, how do I export that all in one PDF at the end because that is my ultimate goal

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to move the chart from one workbook to another workbook However, this only allows me to create a new sheet in the source workbook. Any way around this?

Comment: Is there anyway I could create a template sheet in the current workbook and copy all the graphs there?